# Problem while upgrading (dependency problems)

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, dpkg

When i try to upgrade with **apt-get upgrade** on Ubuntu Server **14.04 LTS**, i get this log:

[Click here for the log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9043156/)

It says that there are some problem with the dependencies of these packages:

- **udev**
- **systemd-services**
- **libpam-systemd:amd64**
- **linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic**
- **linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic**
- **linux-image-generic**
- **linux-generic**
- **linux-server**

Note that i get these errors also with **apt-get install** and other install/remove's commands.

What should i do to fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I have run these commands, as written in the answer below:

- **sudo chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc**
- **sudo apt-get -f install**
- **sudo dpkg --configure -a**

Now **apt-get upgrade** returns this log:

[Click here for the log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9043687/)

There are some problem only with these packages:

- **udev**
- **systemd-services**
- **libpam-systemd:amd64**

However the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

This should install all missing dependencies and configure dpkg.

Comment: Here's first command's log: [click me](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9043381/)
And here's second command's log: [click me](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9043408/)

Comment: Try the second command.

Comment: **apt-get upgrade** returns the same errors

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc` and then try the above two commands.

Comment: I always get a dependency's problem, but now log says that there are some problems only with **udev**, **systemd-services** and **libpam-systemd:amd64**.

Comment: Post the log if possible. Did you now try to run the two commands above?

Comment: Here's **apt-get upgrade**'s log: [click me](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9043687/). I have already run those commands.

Comment: Try `cat /dev/null > /var/run/utmp` and restart the computer.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Apparently it is because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1377624) in systemd.

Comment: So this problem is unsolvable, isn't it?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 uses upstart by default instead of systemd. Did you install systemd separately?

Comment: I think no, i have only bought a VPS from OVH.

Comment: This problem is common with OVH VPS. Other users are also reporting the same in the aforementioned bug page.

Comment: I understand, so i have to resign.